# Typescript type string is not assignable to type keyof when I get value from object

Tags: typescript

Could someone explains why in the example code below typescript gives the error message "const key: string
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Condition"

```ts
interface Condition {
    GOOD: 'GOOD';
    BAD: 'BAD';
    NONE: 'NONE';
}

const ObjWithAllCondition: Condition = {
    GOOD: 'GOOD',
    BAD: 'BAD',
    NONE: 'NONE',
};

interface Result {
    condition: keyof Condition;
    count: number;
}

const getKeyValue = <T extends Condition, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key];

const getResult = (): Result[] => {
    const result = [];
    for (const key in ObjWithAllCondition) {
        result.push({
            condition: getKeyValue(ObjWithAllCondition, key), // this is error
            count: 1,
        });
    }

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because TypeScript uses a [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) type system, all objects *can* have extra properties beyond what exists in its defined type (and the compiler is ok with this as long as the properties that *are* known are assignable to the type of the object).

Because of this, using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) or methods which iterate an object's keys might return values which are not in the type that you're expecting, so all of those keys/properties are of the type `string` (for type safety).

You can refactor your example to derive the properties in your `Condition` type from an array of the possible keys, and then use that array when iterating the keys. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-mUkSi0RisbJWRNOWjeWd3gGjKDwTAAIwJgMVXlAmAVMWLXVQCx2Wa6mVQGFOIA)

```ts
const conditions = ['GOOD', 'BAD', 'NONE'] as const;
type ConditionName = typeof conditions[number];

type StringUnionToKV<S extends string> = { [K in S]: K };

type Condition = StringUnionToKV<ConditionName>;

const obj: Condition = {
  GOOD: 'GOOD',
  BAD: 'BAD',
  NONE: 'NONE',
};

type Result = {
  condition: ConditionName;
  count: number;
};

const getKeyValue = <T extends Condition, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key];

const getResult = (): Result[] => {
  const result = [];

  for (const key of conditions) {
    result.push({
      condition: getKeyValue(obj, key),
      count: 1,
    });
  }

  return result;
};
```

> If you are going to be working with a fixed set of strings, you might also be interested in [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums).

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried using enum but had had the same issue and decided to use object